# Why does fasttext yield <\s> as first entry in VSM?

Tags: fasttext

I am using a large German corpus, which I have cleaned of all special characters/numbers/inter-punctuation signs.
Each line contains one sentence.

Running

```
fastText/./fasttext skipgram -input input.txt -output output.txt
-minCount 2 -minn 2 -maxn 8 -dim 300 -ws 5
```

returns a VSM with `<\s>` as first entry.
From how I understand it, there are white spaces left in the document that are interpreted as a token.
Is that correct?
And how can I get rid of them and/or the `<\s>` in the VSM?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character ? Use NotePad++ to detect / remove it (encoding UTF8-BOM => UTF8)

Comment: Some tools in the word2vec family have created such `'<\s>'` peudowords to indicate the start/finish of each individual text (line of the input file) - but a quick grep through the latest `fasttext` source didn't find a place it's currently being used (though I may have missed it). Is there a chance you're using an older version of `fasttext`? Do you see it even if passing a toy-sized `input.txt`, say one with a single line or even just single word?

Comment: Thanks for your replies! @gojomo, thank you very much. I used both a 2020 version and  a very recent version of fasttext. Using a one-line minimal-sized `input.txt` I don't get the `<\s>` . It then returns only the valid word vectors. I have also manually inserted a line break (`enter` in the corresponding txt file, not `\n`) and also did not obtain any `<\s>`s. I do hoewver get them when I use my large corpus file, which contains many line breaks.

Comment: Aha, my grep hadn't been properly escaped, I see the references in the code & docs now. Answer fothcoming.

Answer (score 1):

By convention the `fasttext` tool converts any newlines in the input file to a pseudoword token `'<\s>'`, to represent an end-of-string ('EOS').

See the discussion in the Python binding Markdown docs:

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/main/python/README.md#important-preprocessing-data--encoding-conventions

> The newline character is used to delimit lines of text. In particular,
> the EOS token is appended to a line of text if a newline character is
> encountered. The only exception is if the number of tokens exceeds the
> MAX_LINE_SIZE constant as defined in the Dictionary header. This means
> if you have text that is not separate by newlines, such as the fil9
> dataset, it will be broken into chunks with MAX_LINE_SIZE of tokens
> and the EOS token is not appended.
>
> The length of a token is the number of UTF-8 characters by considering
> the leading two bits of a byte to identify subsequent bytes of a
> multi-byte sequence. Knowing this is especially important when
> choosing the minimum and maximum length of subwords. Further, the EOS
> token (as specified in the Dictionary header) is considered a
> character and will not be broken into subwords.

(Though only mentioned in that doc about the Python bindings, it's definitely defined/implemented in the core C++ code, especially the [`dictionary.cc`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/a20c0d27cd0ee88a25ea0433b7f03038cd728459/src/dictionary.cc#L22) file.)

To eliminate that word-token, you'd have to strip all newlines from your input file.